# What is the difference between "This area is infested" and "This area is overrun by monsters"?

Tags: stardew-valley

Sometimes when exploring the mine I see levels with high amount of monsters (primarily slimes). There are two different messages about such levels:

- This area is infested
- This area is overrun by monsters

In both cases you need to kill every monster on the floor to ladder to appear. So, what is the difference?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

So, I was curious, and I've peek into the decompiled code.
It was found that there is no difference between this two messages. It just picks one at random to show:

```
Game1.showGlobalMessage(Game1.content.LoadString(random.NextDouble() < 0.5 ? "Strings\\Locations:Mines_Infested" : "Strings\\Locations:Mines_Overrun"));
```

Answer (score 1):

I did a bit of searching and it seems that there's is no difference. Every site I come across says something like this : "If a level is "infested" or "overrun" by monsters, all enemies must be defeated on that floor before a ladder will appear" [From the wiki, third line](http://stardewvalleywiki.com/The_Mines).

Another source:
"For one, you may encounter a level that indicates it has been "infested" by monsters. On these levels you must kill every enemy in order to spawn the ladder." [Guide to The Mines (Spoiler alert!)](http://www.gamerevolution.com/faq/stardew-valley/a-guide-to-completing-the-mines-122927)

It's just kill every monster and there seems to be 0 difference in "infested" or "overrun".

Answer (score -4):

The difference is if an area is "infested" it has a much greater amount of monsters. If an area is overrun it has the same amount of monsters as an infested area but the monsters found here have a greater chance to be rare more powerful monsters. The actual amount of monsters varies little, but the specific type and power is determined by which message you see.

Comment: Since Exerion looked into the code and found there is no difference, this answer is wrong.

Comment: This is the first I've ever heard of this theory, and I've been following this game's development since it was released. I strongly doubt this answer is correct, especially since it looks like @Exerion already decompiled the code and found how the text is generated (it's random each time and has nothing to do with what monsters spawn).